# How to load a large size image after a small size image has loaded and showed on an UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, sdwebimage

I can use the SDWebImage to load a small size image with an url to show on an UIImageView. But I don't know how to load a larger size image with another url to show on the same UIImageView after I has loaded the smaller size image.

```
[aImageView setImageWithURL:fristUrl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] success:^(UIImage *image) {
    [aImageView setImageWithURL:secondUrl placeholderImage:image success:^(UIImage *image) {
        ;
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error105size:%@", [error description]);
    }];
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error50size:%@", [error description]);
}];
```

I has used the code above, but it crashed.
Hope your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Developer.Apple example [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Please read [ReadMe.txt](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_13) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to create any hidden `UIImageView` to do the trick.

What you must do is set the first URL (with the smaller image) to be directly downloaded into your `UIImageView`, and then use `SDWebImageManager` to download the larger version on the background. When it finishes download, simply set the downloaded image in your image view.

Here's how you can do that:

```
// First let the smaller image download naturally
[self.imageView setImageWithURL:self.imageURL];

// Slowly download the larger version of the image
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadWithURL:self.currentPhoto.largeImageURL options:SDWebImageLowPriority progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {
    if (image) {
        [self.imageView setImage:image];
    }
}];
```

Note how I used `SDWebImageLowPriority` option. This way, the image (which should be naturally larger than the first one) will be downloaded in a low priority and should not cancel the first download.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[btn sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:obj.thumbnail_pic] forState:UIControlStateNormal placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photoDefault.png"] options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
    NSLog(@"img samll download ok:%@",obj.thumbnail_pic);
    if (image) {
         [btn sd_setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[ctl getBigImg:obj.thumbnail_pic]] forState:UIControlStateNormal
                placeholderImage:image];
    }
}];
```